# C++ 11 - Tuple of Arrays from Array of Tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic

Given a std::tuple, e.g.:

```
std::tuple<int, float, char>
```

I'd like to generate a type like this:

```
std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>, std::vector<char>>
```

as you can see, is a tuple of vectors of original types.
here's the standard scenario:

```
typedef std::tuple<int, float, char>    Struct;          // scenario 1
typedef std::vector<Struct>             ArrayOfStructs;  // scenario 2
typedef HereIsTheQuestion<Struct>::Type StructOfArrays;  // scenario 3
```

Scenario 1 is intended to be accessed like this:

```
Struct x = ...; // single tuple
std::get<0>(x) = 11;
// etc.
```

Scenario 2 is intended to be accessed like this:

```
ArrayOfStructs xs = ...; // array of tuples
for (size_t i=0; i<xs.size(); ++i) {
    std::get<0>(xs[i]) = 11;
    // etc.
}
```

Scenario 3 is intended to be accessed like this:

```
StructsOfArrays xs = ...; // single tuple of arrays
size_t n = std::get<0>(xs).size(); // first tuple array size
for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    std::get<0>(xs)[i] = 11;
    // etc.
}
```

How must HereIsTheQuestion::Type be written to resemble a tuple of arrays from the original Struct type?

Thanks,
m.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how `HereIsTheQuestion` should be implemented.

```
template<typename T>       //primary template
struct HereIsTheQuestion;  //leave it undefined

template<typename ...T>
struct HereIsTheQuestion<std::tuple<T...>>  //partial specialization
{
    using Type = std::tuple<std::vector<T>...>;
};
```

Now

```
HereIsTheQuestion<std::tuple<int, float, char>>::Type
```

is

```
std::tuple<std::vector<int>,std::vector<float>, std::vector<char>>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @spattija: Yes, empty tuple will yield empty tuple for `::Type`, that is, `HereIsTheQuestion<std::tuple<>>::Type` would be `std::tuple<>`.

Comment: As for my ignorance, I wrote BlahBlah<...>::Type, do you think it is needed? I mean, can HereIsTheQuestion<...tuple...>::Type be replaced with HereIsTheQuestion<std::tuple<>> ? (without an internal typedef, --> ::Type) ?

Comment: @spattija: I don't get what you're saying. Please write your code on ideone.com, and give me the link.

Comment: @spattija Use a type alias, i.e. `template <typename... T> using HereIsTheQuestion_t = typename HereIsTheQuestion<T...>::type;`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this template to create the type:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename... Ts>
    struct tuple_change { };

    template <typename... Ts>
    struct tuple_change<std::tuple<Ts...>>
    {
        using type = std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>;
    };
}
```

And create an index sequence like this:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <int... Is>
    struct index { };

    template <int N, int... Is>
    struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> { };

    template <int... Is>
    struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : index<Is...> { };
}
```

You also need a template to allow printing of the tuple:

```
template <typename... Ts, int... Is>
static void print(std::tuple<Ts...>& var, detail::index<Is...>)
{
    auto l = { (print(std::get<Is>(var)), 0)... };
    (void)l;
}

template <typename... Ts>
static void print(std::tuple<Ts...>& var)
{
    print(var, detail::gen_seq<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
}

template <typename T>
static void print(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for (auto a : v)
    {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << a << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

After that it becomes simple. Here is your program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

namespace detail
{
    template <typename... Ts>
    struct tuple_change { };

    template <typename... Ts>
    struct tuple_change<std::tuple<Ts...>>
    {
        using type = std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>;
    };

    template <int... Is>
    struct index { };

    template <int N, int... Is>
    struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> { };

    template <int... Is>
    struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : index<Is...> { };
}

template <typename... Args, int... Is>
void fill(std::tuple<Args...>& var, detail::index<Is...>)
{
    auto l = { (std::get<Is>(var).assign(5, 11), 0)... };
    // here I just decided to make the size 5
    (void)l;
}

template <typename... Args>
void fill(std::tuple<Args...>& var)
{
    fill(var, detail::gen_seq<sizeof...(Args)>{});
}

template <typename T>
static void print(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for (auto a : v)
    {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << a << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename... Ts, int... Is>
static void print(std::tuple<Ts...>& var, detail::index<Is...>)
{
    auto l = { (print(std::get<Is>(var)), 0)... };
    (void)l;
}

template <typename... Ts>
static void print(std::tuple<Ts...>& var)
{
    print(var, detail::gen_seq<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
}

using result_type = detail::tuple_change<std::tuple<int, bool>>::type;

int main()
{
    result_type r;

    fill(r);
    print(r);
}
```

***[Demo](http://ideone.com/0awFNP#view_edit_box)***

Comment: @spattija What is your intent? You have three different scenarios and I'm not sure what you want done.

Comment: @spattija Did you not want to change it into a tuple of vectors? That's what I did here. I also included a way to print the tuple with a demo.